# Why is instanceof doing memory allocation on android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to eliminate all the memory allocation during gameplay on my game and I have stuck to something strange that I never saw in the past, for some reason the use of instanceof is doing memory allocation on android, why is that?

[image]

This is the full code of OrangeFollower.java:

```
package enemies;

import game.ConcreteBodySystem;
import game.Tags;
import main.MainGame;
import player.Player;
import tools.Director;
import tools.FastMath;
import tools.Vector;
import tools.gColor;
import worldsystem.BlockCollitionSystem;
import worldsystem.Entity;
import worldsystem.IntervalSystem;
import worldsystem.SoundSystem;
import worldsystem.SpriteSystem;
import worldsystem.gWorld;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;

public class OrangeFollower extends Enemy {

public static int TAG=gWorld.getNextTag();
public OrangeFollower(final gWorld world) {
    super(world);
    this.tag =TAG;

    initScale(0.8f,0.8f);
    initColor(1,0.6f,0, 1);
    initColScale(0.4f, 0.4f);
    initSpeed(0.018f);
    setGroups(Tags.GROUP_CONCRETE_ENEMIES,Tags.GROUP_DESTRACTABLE,Tags.GROUP_ENEMIE,Tags.GROUP_GREEN_ENEMIES,Tags.GROUP_MOVING);

    SpriteSystem sm=(SpriteSystem) addSystem(new SpriteSystem(this, "sprites/sprites2.png",896,256,1,128,128,pos,scale,rotation,new gColor(1,1,1,1)));

    addSystem(new ConcreteBodySystem(this));

    addSystem(new EnemieSystem(this,2,20,false,true,false,false,Tags.GROUP_GREEN_ENEMIES){{multis=2;}});
    addSystem(new BlockCollitionSystem(this,256,true){
        @Override
        public void colliding(Entity e) {
            super.colliding(e);
            if(e instanceof Generator)return;
            Vector.vector.set(e.pos.x-pos.x, e.pos.y-pos.y);
            float length = FastMath.sqrtBlazingFast(Vector.vector.x*Vector.vector.x  + Vector.vector.y*Vector.vector.y);
            if (length != 0) {
                Vector.vector.x = Vector.vector.x / length;
                Vector.vector.y = Vector.vector.y / length;

                vel.x-=Vector.vector.x;
                vel.y-=Vector.vector.y;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    speed=realSpeed;
}
@Override
public void update() {
    super.update();
    pos.x += (vel.x * speed) * Director.delta;
    pos.y += (vel.y * speed) * Director.delta;
}
```

}

Comment: I think he's referring to the classloader loading `Generator`. Is that the first occurance of the type?

Comment: Beware that the Android runtime _is not_ the "official" Java runtime; therefore any knowledge of the latter you would previously have will not apply. This is really an Android specific question.

Comment: @JoopEggen ,yep seems that the class is refereed to for the first time,It didn't crossed my mind that a simple instanceof check needs to load the class(I am naive :) ).Post an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is initialized for the first time.

- An inner class is not necessarily initialized when the outer class is. Again the java reference says: first use.
- Memory allocation not only happens with `new` at the object instantiations, but also at the ClassLoaders.
- What happens on Android is yet another affair, but fortunately Google still keeps close to processing model of the official JVMs.

As extracted from comments by @VinceEmigh, @SteveL, @fge.